# Adding Product error Magento2

Tags: magento2, product

When i add a new product and it was error as the following message "There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1245911347200".

Comment: Can you Please check error log.

Comment: can you please go to var/report/ folder and copy, paste this error log here?

Comment: Please check product stock qty. It should be more than 0.
Also Enable developer mode. So you can check error in browser instead of repoting to file.

Answer (score 0):

Before dealing with error, you need to see full error text.

If you have an error log record number, you just need to open a report file with name, corresponding to this number. All reports are located in the folder `var/report`.

For example, if you have **Error log record number: 1245911347200**, then proper report will be `[Magento Root Directory]/var/report/1245911347200`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please show me detail how to access to Magento root directory/ var/report.